# SQL Date format in AND command

Tags: mysql, datetime, datatable, formatting, simpledateformat

I need to set the date format in SQL in between AND command.

```
Select firstname,lastname from school
where teacher='contractor'
and active='1'
and contractenddate is not null 
( here i need to set the date format to YYYYMMDD)
```

Comment: What do you mean "Set the date format" ? Do you mean the `contractenddate` is not a DATE or DATETIME datatype?

Comment: I meant the contractenddate format to YYYYMMDD

Comment: `SELECT contractenddate + 0 AS contractenddate ...`

Comment: It should already be `yyyy-mm-dd` So do you mean you want to adjust that to actually be `yyyymmdd`

Comment: since I am using And contractorenddate as null I need the actual formating

Comment: show the query you want to get to. I for one dont understand what you are asking us to help with

Comment: this is the query I am trying to run  ... here the contract end date is coming up with different data format and I need to have my output with YYYY-MM-DD  format.    
         SELECT firstname,lastname FROM School
          WHERE teacher='contractor'
          AND contractenddate IS NOT NULL

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You want to format the "contract end date" in your SQL's output - but there is no such field in your output. There is only `firstname` and `lastname`. There is also nothing relevant to format in your `where` clause, since that does not refer to any specific date values - only to `NOT NULL`. Is there something missing from your query? Please [edit] your question, to clarify (don't provide clarifications in comments, for this).